# How to convert Date into UTC in Java?

Tags: java, date, date-conversion

Say apology to ask repeated Question but i'm so confused to convert this time into UTC.

In my Application taking current System Date

```
Date date1 = new Date();//Fri Jul 26 10:34:06 IST 2013
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ");
```

then i have a drop down list (i'm using [Selectbox timezone list](http://michaelapproved.com/articles/timezone-dropdown-select-list))

if an indian user select `GMT+05:30`

now i want to convert `date1` in UTC time using `GMT+05:30` like `Fri Jul 26 05:00:06 IST 2013`

So Every user select some timezone only but in that timezone using server current Date and Time it will be convert to UTC time

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
System.out.println(f.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Where i can give timezone value like GMT+05:30 or GMT+06:30.

Comment: cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5); // here 5 in hours 
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // 30 in minutes

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String tz = "GMT+05:30";
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz));
    System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
```

Note that it will never print IST because GMT+05:30 is not equivalent to IST.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```